# Dropdown Menu Not Responding with JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have the following base.html and navbar.html files and I am trying to add the Dropdown Menu portion to my Navbar. The menu shows up, but does not 'dropdown' or respond at all to a click. My troubleshooting led me to other posts where I added the following lines to my navbar.html file with no luck. I also tried adding it to the beginning (and end) of the other scripts in my base.html with no change either.

JQuery

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

base.html

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
  {% comment %} <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" /> {% endcomment %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-vKMx8UnXk60zUwyUnUPM3HbQo8QfmNx7+ltw8Pm5zLusl1XIfwcxo8DbWCqMGKaWeNxWA8yrx5v3SaVpMvR3CA=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  <link href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">  
  {% block extracss %}{% endblock %}
  <title>{% block title %}title{% endblock title %}</title>
</head>

<body style='background-color:#e7e7e7;'>
  {% include 'include/navbar.html' %}
  <div class='row' style='background-color: orange;'>
    <div class='column' style='padding-left:35px ;float: left; width:17%;background-color: #f1f1f1;'> 
      test
    </div>
    <div class='column' style='float: right; width:83%;background-color: #e7e7e7; padding:25px'>
      {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
    </div>
  </div>
  {% include 'cms/modal/modal.html' %}
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-+YQ4JLhjyBLPDQt//I+STsc9iw4uQqACwlvpslubQzn4u2UU2UFM80nGisd026JF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/toastr.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-VEd+nq25CkR676O+pLBnDW09R7VQX9Mdiij052gVCp5yVH3jGtH70Ho/UUv4mJDsEdTvqRCFZg0NKGiojGnUCw=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'cms/js/ajax.js' %}"></script>
  {% block extrajs %}{% endblock extrajs %}
</body>
</html>
```

navbar.html

```
{% load static %}
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand"
          href="{% if user.is_staff or user.is_superuser %}{% url 'admin:index' %}{% else %}{% url 'app:home' %}{% endif %}">
          <img src="{% static 'img/bootstrap-solid.svg' %}" width="21" height="21" alt="Logo" class="mr-2 mt-n1">xxx
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault"
          aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          </ul>
          <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'account:logout' %}"> Sign out <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></a>
      </div>
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Menu</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: where is your own jQuery code?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues here:

1. You're importing JQuery twice. Once in `JQuery` and once in `base`. Remove the `slim` one from your `JQuery`.
2. You are importing Bootstrap CSS for `4.0.0`, but JS for `4.6.0`. You need to use the same version for both `CSS` and `JS`.
3. You are using the syntax `data-*` and also `data-bs-*`. The first one is for Bootstrap 4 and the latter one is for Bootstrap 5. You cannot mix these. Choose 1 version and go with it.

Here are the import links for Bootstrap 5:

CSS: `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">`

JS: `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

And here's a sample B5 dropdown:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown button
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

[B5 Dropdown Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/)

Note: If you are only importing the JQuery for Bootstrap, then you can remove that as well since B5 doesn't need JQuery.